Dark Theme Tag Pop Especially Bright
I'm not sure when the tag-popup changed, but when activated by mouse-over, the button color is a bit over-bright for the dark theme and the rest of the text in the popup. For example,

As a suggestion, it looks like if the button (highlight behind "Watch tag") was reduced to just occupy the center 1/3 of the dialog, the same attention grabbing effect could be achieved without the full-width (or 90% or whatever it is) that draws the eyes away from the rest of the text. I do see the intent to be to have a consistent margin/padding for the dialog text and button, so another option may be to tone down the highlight color.
This isn't to say the way it is is bad or wrong or looks bad, just the highlight seems to overpower the remaining text in the dialog. It caught my attention, as it usually does by accidental mouse-over, so I thought I would pass it along for discussion. It certainly isn't any type of major issue.

"it looks like if the button (highlight behind "Watch tag") was reduced to just occupy the center 1/3 of the dialog" the button was expanded - there used to be two buttons taking up equal space next to each other (the other was "Ignore tag"). That was tested a few weeks back and SE declared it a success. Although, they've not really shared what metrics they chose for this. Tag hover experiment wrap-up and next steps. So, the button used to be closer to 1/3 the width before. Now it's big and bright.

I see suggestions and see-something-say-something helpful comments are still received with the usual meta flare. Like I said, it isn't any type of major issue, but you would think it would be wise to encourage all users to pass along areas where improvements could be made. That just sounds like good policy.

Are you saying the button size is only an issue in dark mode? Because the same button is the same size in light mode - one could argue that if the issue was with UI layout and sizing that the light/dark mode is less relevant.

I'm saying I only noticed it in dark mode. That's the only mode I use on SO. And this is for discussion. I had the impression on mouse-over that the button was too big and too bright for the popup and it made the text more difficult to read due to it's lesser contrast with the background. That's how it ht me. If you think it's great or fine - that's okay too. But for my near 60 year old eyes, it would help to tone down the button brightness or size a bit to make it less distracting and make the text describing the tag easier to read. I can read it fine this is a "make it better" suggestion.

@DrewReese of course a bright button's size is only an issue in dark mode. In light mode you don't get the same effect - a biggish dark shape in light background does not immediately blind you and/or sharply grab your attention, as a biggish bright shape on dark background.

@VLAZ In light mode the button is an equally obtrusive and distracting dark blotch in an otherwise sea of white. ‍♂️ I think I get what you are saying though. It's not the size so much then, but the actual contrast ratio between button and background. I was wanting to understand what the bedrock concern was.

All eyes are different I guess, that button doesn't strike me as "blinding" in the slightest. The contrast is quite gentle to me. The button text is a little on the small side though, a large button with such small text is out of whack. Clearly, the button should be smaller.

@Gimby The screenshot here doesn't accurately represent how it looks in reality because MSO has a light mode. If the website is entirely in dark, then any bright spot stands out a lot. Especially consider that dark mode is paired with IRL darkness. Late at night, if I am viewing a page in dark mode something large and contrasting, it's a very big visual disruption. While if there is already a lot of light showing a dark shape is noticeable but not as disruptive. Showing a dark mode screenshot in a light mode frame doesn't accurately capture what it's like for another light object to be there
